# Unable to update realm object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am updating an object in realm with swift but getting an error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'

My code:-

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let cont = Contact()
cont.notes = self.notee
cont.id = self.oneCont.id //i.e id of current object
cont.email = self.email


try! self.realm.write {
   self.realm.add(cont,update:true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a local realm with

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

but then you're writing to a class var realm with

```
try! self.realm.write {
```

you should change that to use the same local realm

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let cont = Contact()
cont.notes = self.notee
cont.id = self.oneCont.id //i.e id of current object
cont.email = self.email

try! realm.write {
   realm.add(cont,update:true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb with Realm is to use the Realm instance on the same thread it was created. In your code sample, you seem to create a realm instance but later you use `self.realm`. You probably just need to use the Realm instance you've just created.

Comment: Can you tell on which line the crash occurs please ? (you can use the exception breakpoint to know for sure)